# I get an error in my code: Cannot find table 0. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

I get an error in my code: Cannot find table 0. what am I doing wrong?

```
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from User where username=? and password=?", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Select the username and password from mysql database in login table

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;
        //use asp login control to check username and password

        //Session["UserID"] = "usrName";
        //set the UserID from the User Table unsure how to add this to the sql syntax above

        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
        // If row exists, the login is successful  

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow dp = dt.Rows[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            Session["UserID"] = Convert.ToString(dp["UserID"]);
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx");
            // Event Authenticate is true forward to user profile
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: and also, don't do select *, only return what you actually need.  in this case, it looks like you should just be doign "select UserID..."

Comment: You should dispose the DB stuff in `using` statements.  Also, you don't need to initialize `dr`.

Comment: I would like to just get the error fixed im unsure how to fix it if some one can post an asnwer to correct my error that would be kind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates an empty dataset, then tries to get a table from it.
Since you never put anything in the dataset, you get an error.

You need to use the `DataReader` that you got back from your query (use the `HasRows` property).

However, I **strongly** recommend that you

## Use ASP.Net's built-in forms authentication system

instead.  It will save you lots of code and is more secure.

Comment: I think the issue is with the actual query, not the code afterwards.

Comment: @Josh: No; SQL wouldn't give that error.  Run `new DataSet().Tables[0]` in LINQPad and you get this exact error.

Comment: cant use has rows mono crashes with hasrows

Comment: Then you can call `Read()` and check its return value.

Comment: @SLaks, do you recommend using just Forms auth, or that coupled with the built in `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` provider?

Answer (score 1):

Put `User` in brackets: `[User]` - it is a reserved.

I see you're using MySQL - I think it is double quotes then: `"User"`

Comment: No.  His query is succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

Do your parameters need to be in the query the same way?

instead of

```
"Select * from User where username=? and password=?"
```

should that be

```
"Select * from User where username=@username and password=@password",
```

**Edit**: this might be way off, it might be something specific to our internal sqlcommand stuff?

Comment: No.  His query is succeeding.

Comment: you can use either `?` or `@` in at least MySQL.